# Unable to logout session in PHP

Tags: php

I tried a login and logout function in a signin bootstrap theme and it worked fine. But am not able to logout the session in my other tenplate when I use the same code which I used previously which worked. I tried all most all the solutions found in internet. I am getting a blank page when I click on Logout link.

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
header('location:index.php');
}
?>
---html code---

<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'foodchain');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
  $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);


  $sql = "SELECT email,password FROM user_register WHERE email='$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);


  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($count == 1) {

   $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

    header('Location:index.php');
 }else {

     $logmsg = "Invalid Username or Password";


  }
}
?>
```

**check_login.php**

```
 <?php
 session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['login_user']) || empty($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
 header('location:login.php');
 }
?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 session_destroy();
 header("Location:login.php");
 die();
 ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include('check_login.php');
?>
```

Its perfectly working when I don't use the template(downloaded from some website), or when I use the bootsrap signin template.

Comment: If you post the code I would be happy to look it over, otherwise this is too vague to diagnose I think.

Comment: If you arer getting a white page it means there is some error and the error display is disabled. YOu need to get the exact error by enabling error display. In your php file by using `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You really should provide us with some source code, links to things that you've tried, what you've previously tried, what errors you received, etc. From what I can gather, you're looking for a logout page using sessions? Here's what I've got.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location: ..');
?>
```

Comment: I have edited my question @Sims. Thank you for your response.

Comment: No problem. If it helped, please accept it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The key part is setting $_SESSION to an empty array.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Nino. I solved the problem by just deleting all the mobile, smartphone, app folders and htaccess file which where bundled with the downloaded template. I finally found a solution after weeks.